# Meteor Email Error

Tags: email, meteor

I'm having issues sending email messages with Metoer. Im getting "Email is not defined" error.
I've tried "meteor add email" but it didnt help.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

did you setup the `MAIL_URL` environment variable ?

From meteor docs :

The server reads from the `MAIL_URL` environment variable to determine how to send mail. Currently, Meteor supports sending mail over SMTP; the `MAIL_URL` environment variable should be of the form `smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT`/.

For apps deployed with meteor deploy, `MAIL_URL` defaults to an account (provided by [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)) which allows apps to send up to 200 emails per day; you may override this default by assigning to `process.env.MAIL_URL` before your first call to Email.send.

If `MAIL_URL` is not set (eg, when running your application locally), `Email.send` outputs the message to standard output instead.

Comment: Yeah I defined the MAIL_URL as per this article: http://blog.ploki.info/post/35718279108/send-email-with-meteor-mailgun
Also tried deploying to the meteor server, which as per the excerpt above would automatically configure the MAIL_URL. Even without it configured, it should still send the message to standard output